# How to replace an OR statement from a join in sql server

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following query that uses an or statement on a join, so basically if one condition on the join isn't met it must check the next condition. The problem is that with the OR statement it takes really long to run but when I remove one of the OR conditions it runs instantly. is there a better way to do this with both conditions without using the OR statement so it would speed up the query

```
  select t5.TransactionNumber
        ,t4.ID
        ,t3.[Entry] AS Amount 
        ,t2.Address AS AddressDetail
        ,t1.PhoneNumber   AS  ContactNumber
  FROM Table1 t1 (NOLOCK)
  JOIN Table2 t2 (NOLOCK) ON t2.FicaID = t1.FicaId 
  inner  join Table3 t3 (NOLOCK) ON (t3.ID = t2.ID AND t3.Code = t2.Code) or (t3.TypeID = t2.TypeID)  //on this join i have an or statement if one condition isnt met it must check the next condition
  LEFT JOIN Table4 t4 (NOLOCK) ON t4.Result = t3.Result
  LEFT JOIN Table5 t5 (NOLOCK) ON t5.AccNum = t3.AccNum
  where t1.date>'2018-09-01' and t1.date<'2018-09-30'
```

Comment: You can put your or condition to where clause and might create an index on those columns.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai then how i would join onto that table?

Comment: Join condition and where condition works in similar manner. They both used to filter the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try by using left join and COALESCE function

```
select t5.TransactionNumber
        ,t4.ID
        ,COALESCE(t3.[Entry],t33.[Entry]) AS Amount 
        ,t2.Address AS AddressDetail
        ,t1.PhoneNumber   AS  ContactNumber
  FROM Table1 t1 (NOLOCK)
  JOIN Table2 t2 (NOLOCK) ON t2.FicaID = t1.FicaId 
  left  join Table3 t3 (NOLOCK) ON (t3.ID = t2.ID AND t3.Code = t2.Code)
  left join Table3 t33  (t33.TypeID = t2.TypeID)  //I moved it to left join
  LEFT JOIN Table4 t4 (NOLOCK) ON t4.Result = t3.Result
  LEFT JOIN Table5 t5 (NOLOCK) ON t5.AccNum = t3.AccNum
  where t1.date>'2018-09-01' and t1.date<'2018-09-30'
```

Comment: i tried this but it ignores the other condition,it only reads the first condition and doesnt read the other. so for example what if both conditions return true,its not detecting both

Comment: @john or also works same if 1st condition met then no need 2nd condition

Comment: so if the first condition isnt met then it will try the second condition?

Comment: @john of-course it will , because if 1st condition then it will get data from that because COALESCE function get 1st non null value

Comment: i just swooped the conditions around for a test and its still not giving me back any information, but there is data because when i run my query how it was previously it returns information

Answer (score 2):

By the rule of distributivity in logic,

P OR (Q AND R) can be written as
(P OR Q) AND (P OR R).. maybe that helps?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query :

```
 select * from
 (
  select t5.TransactionNumber
        ,t4.ID
        ,t3.[Entry] AS Amount 
        ,t2.Address AS AddressDetail
        ,t1.PhoneNumber   AS  ContactNumber
         FROM Table1 t1 (NOLOCK)
        JOIN Table2 t2 (NOLOCK) ON t2.FicaID = t1.FicaId 
        inner  join Table3 t3 (NOLOCK) ON (t3.ID = t2.ID AND t3.Code = t2.Code)
        )A
         join Table3 t3 (NOLOCK) ON (A.TypeID = t3.TypeID)   

        LEFT JOIN Table4 t4 (NOLOCK) ON t4.Result = t3.Result
        LEFT JOIN Table5 t5 (NOLOCK) ON t5.AccNum = t3.AccNum
        where t1.date>'2018-09-01' and t1.date<'2018-09-30'
```

Comment: this says table 2 can not be bound